# Have ImageJ automatically overwrite when using saveAs

Tags: java, imagej

I'm currently using the ij.jar in a Java application and using ImageJ to save some processed images to the disk.  However, if I try to save an image to a file that already exists, the save fails silently.  The original file remains untouched and ImageJ does not throw an error.

Here is a sample piece of code:

```
IJ.saveAs(image, filename);
```

Is there a way to have saveAs automatically overwrite if a file with the same name already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll be best off using the `FileSaver` class ([`ij.io.FileSaver`](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/developer/source/ij/io/FileSaver.java.html)) instead of the generic `saveAs` method.  For example, if your `ImagePlus` is `image`, then you can save it as a TIFF stack with:

```
new FileSaver(image).saveAsTiffStack(path);
```

If you need another format, have a look at [the documentation](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/ij/io/FileSaver.html), and you'll see that there are similar methods for other formats.

Comment: @Mark_Longair is the filename included in the path?

Comment: @Ivan: yes, the path should be a `String` including the filename